# Tackling the unanswered list

Tags: discussion

This is similar to the thread [90 unanswered questions and counting](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/90-unanswered-questions-and-counting), I have just tackled and answered 4 unanswered questions - it took a bit of research, but was doable and I think the answers are of a reasonable quality.

Why am I mentioning this?

There is quite a bit of talk about good questions attracting experts, but I believe it is a case of good questions *and answers* would attract even more - I found this to be true when I used to run a forum (and yes, I know SE is not a forum, but a similar principle exists), that it is good content that attracts new visitors - as with the evidence of expertise in both questions and answers.

Time?  heck, I have 4 jobs and I can still do this. The questions I answer are more often than not beyond my expertise area... so are a challenge, but an enjoyable challenge.

Comment: 4 jobs? do you live on earth?

Comment: most of the time

Comment: I do think that a lot of the highly voted unanswered questions are just not answerable at the moment... We are not quite at the level of quantum physics, but there are natural barriers that prevent us from having those answers....

Comment: ironically, we need a quantum computer

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/303/90-unanswered-questions-and-counting