# Is there any more that I can do?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Looking at the [Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science%5C), we seem to be floundering in a couple of areas, in particular, questions per day and visits per day.  What I have been doing (when I get time):

- [Tackling the unanswered list](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/tackling-the-unanswered-list)
- Advertising the site on my Facebook, Twitter and ResearchGate accounts (the Twitter one has been favourited since).
- Advertising specific questions on my Twitter and Facebook accounts (1 has been retweeted and 1 other has been favourited).
- Spoken with my University supervisor (I am an Adjunct Lecturer) and we are looking at ways to get the site's name into the University and our affiliated Universities.
- Posting (hopefully) insightful questions and answers.
- Voting
- Flagging, editing and and tag-wiki editing.
- Attending to the review queue, when necessary

Now, it is not much as I have 4 jobs and work 8-12 hours a day, 7 days a week (and hospital visits chew up the time too).  But what else can I do to help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most important thing to do is not the things we can do ourselves, that is voting, answering, posting, etc.
We simply need more people. How to achieve this?

1. Most of us are graduate students. Tell your friends! I noticed that most of my friends are already familiar with Stack Overflow. So just tell them that there is a similar site, only focused on earth science. If they are already regular posters on SO, then it becomes much easier for them to join.
2. Put a banner up in your university. Maybe one of us who has some graphical skills can design a colorful (A4?) poster that you can print, suggesting that students post their questions (even homework questions) up on this website.
3. I occasionally see earth science related questions on other SE website. [Here's one example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144758/60046) on physics.se and I remember seeing some on chemistry.se. Maybe we should attempt moving these questions over to es.se?